# Can google maps be used on a normal api rather than in google api's?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to use a google map to display a persons information only if he wishes to. Otherwise he will be on another screen doing something else but the map updates automatically even when he is not looking at the map?

And also i want the application to run on all versions of android rather than only a phone which has specific google api's . If i create an application using the third party google add-on, will it also run on a normal device with say like android 2.2 or 2.3.3 version?

Comment: You should split your question in two since you're asking two different questions.

Comment: its kinda inter connected so it would be easier for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

The first thing sounds, like you want to update the map in the background, while your user is not on the `MapActivity`. To do so, you can use a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

---

When using the Google APIs, they have to be installed on the targeted device. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/index?hl=de#useslibrary):

> The `<uses-library>` reference is required, because it enables the
>   build tools to link your application against the Maps external
>   library. It also **ensures that the Android system will not install
>   your application on a device unless the required library is
>   available.**